# Focus on checkbox not consistent with checkbox border and outline

Tags: html, css

I have customized my checkbox css. I have given an outline and a border to my checkbox. When i focus or click on the checkbox, the border and outline are not consistent with it. I tried giving the same border and outline to focus pseudo class, but it is not working.
Below is my HTML and CSS that i am using for the checkbox.

HTML:

```
<label class="form__field__input__label"><input class="form__field__input__checkbox" type="checkbox" name="World languages" value="">World languages</label>
```

CSS:

```
.form__field__input__label {
        flex: 0 0 25%;
        margin: 30px 0;
        display: flex;
        font-family: 'NotoSans';
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 26px;
        color: #4e4f4f;

        .form__field__input__checkbox {
            width: 25px;
            height: 24px;
            margin-right: 15px;
            position: relative;
            border: solid 1px #4e4f4f;
            outline: solid 0.5px $labelColor;
            appearance: none;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: none;
            -ms-appearance: none;

            &:checked::before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                width: 15px;
                height: 14px;
                top: 4px;
                right: 4px;
                background-color: #4e4f4f;
                transition: all 0.3s linear;
            }

            &:checked:focus {
                outline: solid 0.5px $labelColor;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean "it is not consistent" would you explain more? and would you explain what you expect to be .

Answer (score 0):

I think this code could help you -

```css
.form__field__input__label {
        flex: 0 0 25%;
        margin: 30px 0;
        display: flex;
        font-family: 'NotoSans';
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 26px;
        color: #4e4f4f;
    }
        .form__field__input__checkbox {
            width: 25px;
            height: 24px;
            margin-right: 15px;
            position: relative;
            border: solid 1px #4e4f4f;
            outline: solid 0.5px $labelColor;
            appearance: none;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: none;
            -ms-appearance: none;
        }
            .form__field__input__checkbox:checked::before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                width: 15px;
                height: 14px;
                top: 4px;
                right: 4px;
                background-color: #4e4f4f;
                transition: all 0.3s linear;
            }

            .form__field__input__checkbox:checked:focus {
                outline: solid 0.5px $labelColor;
            }
```

```html
<label class="form__field__input__label"><input class="form__field__input__checkbox" type="checkbox" name="World languages" value="">World languages</label>
```